# Using an object as database table definition?

Tags: php, mysql, mass-assignment

I need to save an objet I am getting from an API to my own database. The only problem is the object has about...400 different fields? I don't really want to type their definitions all day long, so is there a way to take an object and turn each key into a table column and then insert the values as an insert?

Comment: If you're willing to adjust your database schema to match the object fields, you could use an ORM like Doctrine to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object is a single-dimensional associative array, this should work:

```
// Create a string like field1, field2, field3, ...
$column_list = implode(',', array_columns($object));
// Create placeholder string like :field1, :field2, :field3, ...
$placeholders = implode(',', array_map(function($col) {
    return ":$col";
}, array_columns($object)));
// Put them into the SQL query
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename ($column_list) VALUES ($placeholders)";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
// The object will then be used to supply values for the placeholders
$statement->execute($object);
```